# Trying Analyze Values Between List of Lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 5 lists of variable number of indexes. First one is a lists of Azimutes:

```
lista_az = ['72', '252'], ['90.9', '270.8'], ['78.4', '258.3'], ['280', '100.3'], ['327.1', '147.1'], ['259.1', '293.8', '79.1', '113.8'], ['126.9', '306.8'], ['205.9', '25.9', '41.5', '221.5'] (...)
```

List of Tx:

```
tx = ['8468.00000000 MHz', '8349.00000000 MHz'], ['8349.00000000 MHz', '8468.00000000 MHz'], ['8482.00000000 MHz', '8363.00000000 MHz'], ['8468.00000000 MHz', '8349.00000000 MHz'], ['15.20100000 GHz', '14.78100000 GHz'], ['14.76700000 GHz', '14.80900000 GHz', '15.18700000 GHz', '15.22900000 GHz'], ['1508.50000000 MHz', '1443.00000000 MHz'], ['1450.00000000 MHz', '1515.50000000 MHz', '8468.00000000 MHz', '8349.00000000 MHz'] (...)
```

List of Rx:

```
rx = ['8349.00000000 MHz', '8468.00000000 MHz'], ['8468.00000000 MHz', '8349.00000000 MHz'], ['8363.00000000 MHz', '8482.00000000 MHz'], ['8349.00000000 MHz', '8468.00000000 MHz'], ['14.78100000 GHz', '15.20100000 GHz'], ['15.18700000 GHz', '15.22900000 GHz', '14.76700000 GHz', '14.80900000 GHz'], ['1443.00000000 MHz', '1508.50000000 MHz'], ['1515.50000000 MHz', '1450.00000000 MHz', '8349.00000000 MHz', '8468.00000000 MHz'] (...)
```

List of Polarization:

```
pol = ['V', 'V'], ['H', 'H'], ['V', 'V'], ['V', 'V'], ['V', 'V'], ['V', 'V', 'V', 'V'], ['V', 'V'], ['V', 'V', 'V', 'V'] (...)
```

List of Network:

```
net = ['1', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['3', '3'], ['4', '4'], ['5', '5'], ['6', '6', '6', '6'], ['7', '7'], ['8', '8', '8', '8']
```

I'm trying to compare every element in the same list, for Azimute list:

```
Azimute(list 1) = 252 - 72 =  180 OK
Azimute(list 2) = 90.9 - 270.8 =~ -180 OK
```

Compare first list of Tx and first list of Rx,

```
first tx: 8468.00000000 with second Rx: 8468.00000000, and 
second tx with first rx, and so on.
```

Trying to find matchs (equal values) of tx and rx.

In Polarization list, if first element is equal second, if first is equal third (only if the list have this size), so on.

I tryed do in this:

```
for lista in range(1, len(lista_az)):
    for x in range(0, len(lista_az[lista])-1):
        try:
            if net[lista][x] == net[lista][x+y]:
                if tx[lista][x] == rx[lista][x+y]:
                    if tx[lista][x+y] == rx[lista][x]:
                        if round(abs(float(lista_az[lista][x]) -float(lista_az[lista][x+y]))) == 180:
                            if pol[lista][x] == pol[lista][x+y]:
                                print("Link of list: ", lista)
                                print("Latitude A: ", lat[lista][x]); 
                                print("Latitude B: ", lat[lista][x+y])
                                print("Longitude A: ", lon[lista][x]); print("Longitude B: ", lon[lista][x + y])
                                print("Height A: ", hei[lista][x]); print("Height B: ", hei[lista][x+y])
        except IndexError:
               value = None
```

Expected output would be (for the first list of all lists):

```
first tx = second rx, 8468.00000000 = 8468.00000000 OK next,
second tx = first rx, 8349.00000000 = 8349.00000000 OK next, 
azimute: 72- 252 = 180 is an link OK next,
polarization of first element is equal of second: V = V OK
```

OK this is an Link, after that I'll catch Latitude, Longitude and Height of these two elements. 
But, when loop in a list of more than 2 elements it do not print anything.

Comment: `Compare in first list of Tx and Rx` what does compare mean? Can you share expected output?

Comment: Updated, thank you!